How to get job run_id of run_job_task in an orchestration job?
I have a Databricks job which orchestrates the run of two jobs: job1 and job2 using run_job_task.
job2 depends on job1 and would need to use the run_id of job1 as a parameter. How can this be done?
I see that you can only easily access the task run id of the job {{tasks.job1.run_id}}
